# highcharts grouping with overflow

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I made highcharts for petrol tank(credit prepayment)

I want to make that each line should start from the beginning of the bar instead of grouping(adding) at the end.(I don't need to have sum of all data)

[image]

Thanks.

```
    ![var options = {
                chart: {
                    type: 'bar',
                    height: 300,
                    width:420
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Prepayment'
                },
                yAxis: {
                    gridLineColor: '#eee',
                    title: {
                        text: 'Prepayment'
                    }
                },
                xAxis: {
                    categories: \['Credit'\],
                    labels: {
                        step: 0,
                        rotation: -45,
                        align: 'right'
                    }
                },
                legend: {
                    enabled: true
                },
                tooltip: {
                    shared: true,
                    crosshairs: true
                },
                plotOptions: {
                     series: {
                        stacking: 'normal'
                    }
                },
                credits: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                series: \[{
                    color:'#89C35C',
                    name: 'Current Credit',
                    data: \[10\]                }, {
                    color:'#FFD801',
                    name: 'Warning Threshold',
                    data: \[5\]             }, {
                    color:'#E42217',
                    name: 'Cut-Off Threshold',
                    data: \[1\]             }\],
            };
 $('#container').highcharts(options);][1]
```

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/2se5q/

Comment: You need to disable stacking option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made it like this,where type = area

http://jsfiddle.net/2se5q/4/

[image]

```
    var options = {
                chart: {
                    type: 'area',
                    height: 300,
                    width:420
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Prepayment'
                },
                yAxis: {
                    gridLineColor: '#eee',
                    title: {
                        text: 'Prepayment'
                    }
                },
                xAxis: {
                    categories: ['Credit'],
                    labels: {
                        step: 0,
                        rotation: -45,
                        align: 'right'
                    }
                },
                legend: {
                    enabled: true
                },
                tooltip: {
                    shared: true,
                    crosshairs: true
                },
                plotOptions: {
                     series: {
                        stacking: 'normal'
                    }
                },
                credits: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                series: [{
                    color:'#89C35C',
                    name: 'Current Credit',
                    data: [10,10]               }, {
                    color:'#FFD801',
                    name: 'Warning Threshold',
                    data: [5,5]             }, {
                    color:'#E42217',
                    name: 'Cut-Off Threshold',
                    data: [1,1]             }],
            };
 $('#container').highcharts(options);
```

Answer (score 2):

you will find all the explanations on this link http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts
To answer your question if you delete only "plotOptions:" You will not find more than the sum of the graphics on a line but starting from 0.

Here : http://jsfiddle.net/2se5q/3/

```
 plotOptions: {
    series: {
    stacking: 'normal'
 }
```

Comment: I need to have it on one line instead of separated lines